# Regular expression still allowing tab character to be pasted into form field

Tags: javascript, regex, knockout.js, knockout-validation

Does anyone know why my regex below is still allowing a tab character whitespace to be pasted into a form field? I think I wrote it correctly...

```
/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/g
```

**Suggestion from answer to post:**

```
self.City = ko.observable(model.City).extend({ required: true, maxLength: 30, pattern: /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/ });
```

Comment: `\s`  does it. What do you need to do? If you need a literal space replace `\s` with a space.

Comment: `\s` is a tab, space, or new line.

Comment: Right, so isn't that what I wrote?

Comment: Can you paste numbers or quotes ?

Comment: Try `/^[^\W\S\d_\r\n\t\f]+$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\s`  allows a tab and many more whitespace chars.

If you need a literal space replace `\s` with a space.

You do not need the global modifier either.

Use

```
/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/
```

In Knockout, use

```
self.City = ko.observable(model.City)
    .extend({ required: true })
    .extend({ maxLength: 30 })
    .extend({ pattern: {
              message: 'Only letters and spaces are allowed.',
              params: '^[a-zA-Z ]+$'
     }});
```

Comment: Sorry but this did not work. It still allowed the whitespace created by pasting tab space into field. Any other ideas?

Comment: is it used in `ng-pattern`? Then add `ng-trim="false"`.

Comment: @DeanFriedland Please show, how exactly are you using that regexp to prevent pasting tabs.

Comment: Sure. I'll add it to the OP

Comment: this is Knockout by the way

Comment: Please try the regex in the sample code suggested in the updated answer.